# How can I check the app is movable to sd or not

Tags: android, sd-card, movable

I want to know how to check whether the app is movable to sd or not through code. I know how to get the installed applications list and is it on sd card or not.
If ApplicationInfo flags contains ApplicationInfo.FLAG_EXTERNAL_STORAGE then it is on sd card but how can I check whether the app is movable to sd or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first guess is too look into Android Source code for [`InstalledAppDetails`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#Q_A5W3uqPd4/trunk/Settings/src/com/android/settings/InstalledAppDetails.java&q=WifiEnabler&d=0) activity. This is activity which shows "Move to phone" and "Move to SD card" buttons. It has interesting function called [`initMoveButton`](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#Q_A5W3uqPd4/trunk/Settings/src/com/android/settings/InstalledAppDetails.java&q=WifiEnabler&d=0&l=220):

```
private void initMoveButton() {
    String pkgName = mAppInfo.packageName;
    boolean dataOnly = false;
    ApplicationInfo info1 = null;
    PackageInfo pkgInfo = null;

    try {
        info1 = mPm.getApplicationInfo(pkgName, 0);
        pkgInfo = mPm.getPackageInfo(mAppInfo.packageName,
                PackageManager.GET_UNINSTALLED_PACKAGES);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    }
    dataOnly = (info1 == null) && (mAppInfo != null);
    boolean moveDisable = true;
    if (dataOnly) {
        mMoveAppButton.setText(R.string.move_app);
    } else if ((mAppInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != 0) {
        mMoveAppButton.setText(R.string.move_app_to_internal);
        // Always let apps move to internal storage from sdcard.
        moveDisable = false;
    } else {
        mMoveAppButton.setText(R.string.move_app_to_sdcard);
        if ((mAppInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_FORWARD_LOCK) == 0 &&
                (mAppInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0 &&
                pkgInfo != null) {
            if (pkgInfo.installLocation == PackageInfo.INSTALL_LOCATION_PREFER_EXTERNAL ||
                    pkgInfo.installLocation == PackageInfo.INSTALL_LOCATION_AUTO) {
                moveDisable = false;
            } else if (pkgInfo.installLocation == PackageInfo.INSTALL_LOCATION_UNSPECIFIED) {
                IPackageManager ipm  = IPackageManager.Stub.asInterface(
                        ServiceManager.getService("package"));
                int loc;
                try {
                    loc = ipm.getInstallLocation();
                } catch (RemoteException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Is Pakage Manager running?");
                    return;
                }
                if (loc == PackageHelper.APP_INSTALL_EXTERNAL) {
                    // For apps with no preference and the default value set
                    // to install on sdcard.
                    moveDisable = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if (moveDisable) {
        mMoveAppButton.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        mMoveAppButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        mMoveAppButton.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

Though not all classes used in this functions are available through public API. Specifically `PackageHelper` is internal class.

Comment: pkgInfo.installLocation is not resolvable i.e. I am not able to access installLocation value. Can you help me?

Comment: You can use reflection. This member is there, just not publicly visible

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about that how can I use reflection. Actually, I have no knowledge about reflection.

Comment: why is this link for ....http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

Answer (score 0):

You can get all aplications filter by user and try if packetInfo set filter 'INSTALL_LOCATION_INTERNAL_ONLY'

```
    List<ApplicationInfo> packagesAll = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

    List<ApplicationInfo> packagesByUser = Stream.of(packagesAll)
        .filter((p -> (p.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0))
        .filter((this::tryMoveSDPackage))
        .map(ApplicationInfo::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

private boolean tryMoveSDPackage(ApplicationInfo applicationInfo) {
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(applicationInfo.packageName, 0);
        if (packageInfo.installLocation == PackageInfo.INSTALL_LOCATION_AUTO) {
            //Log.i(TAG, "INSTALL_LOCATION_AUTO");
            return true;
        } else if (packageInfo.installLocation == PackageInfo.INSTALL_LOCATION_PREFER_EXTERNAL) {
            //Log.d(TAG, "INSTALL_LOCATION_PREFER_EXTERNAL");
            return true;
        } else {
            //Log.w(TAG, "INSTALL_LOCATION_INTERNAL_ONLY");
            return false;
        }

    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```