# How do I know if a mobile supports moving an app to sdcard/internal?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I check the app is movable to sd or not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6141592/how-can-i-check-the-app-is-movable-to-sd-or-not)

Like the title described, some devices don't support this feature, eg. galaxy nexus. Is there a way to programmatically check this? (in the InstalledAppDetails.java) .

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6141592/645270)

Comment: I think my question is different from "How can I check the app is movable to sd or not", i mean some device does not support moving function, there is no moveBtn in the manage interface, like the G.N